# Merge two divs with same gradient background

Tags: css

I have a rectangular div and a circular image. I want to set a background of linear-gradient for both elements (without having the circle borders) as shown in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I32u2.png

I have tried to set a linear-gradient background for the circle so it's close to the rectangle and not noticeable. But it does not work with responsive (the borders of the circle are noticeable).

I've also tried to search for online tool to create a circular `clip-path` but I didn't find one.

Any ideas how can I do that?

code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-text">
         <p></p> // and some other text inside the rectangle
    </div>
    <img class="image" src=""></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mask to create the shape:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  border-bottom:50px solid transparent; /* this is the space for your circle */
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,red,blue) border-box;
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) padding-box,
    radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,#fff 98%,transparent)  
     bottom 0 left 50px /* position of circle */
     /160px 160px /*size of circle  */
     no-repeat ;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```